# Does Mono support StringCollections in user settings?

Tags: c#, mono, settings

I've been working on a Winforms application that currently contains a `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` user setting. On Windows, this code works to update and save the setting:

```cs
private void UpdateDirList() {
  Properties.Settings.Default.SearchDirs.Clear();
  Properties.Settings.Default.SearchDirs.AddRange(_searchDirs.ToArray());
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The relevant excerpt from user.config on a Windows machine:

```xml
<setting name="SearchDirs" serializeAs="Xml">
  <value>
    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <string>C:\projects\a</string>
      <string>C:\projects\b</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
  </value>
</setting>
```

When trying to run the same application under Mono, the `<ArrayOfString>` element is missing, even when I've verified that the `Properties.Settings.Default.SearchDirs` object does contain paths:

```xml
<setting name="SearchDirs" serializeAs="Xml">
  <value />
</setting>
```

Does Mono not support StringCollection? Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I worked once with C# for Mono/Linux and Windows. It is not always the same!

I wonder why you use ToArray() at all - needed?
And not ToList()? Does it work? List is IMHO preferred today, it can be used as IEnumerable and IList etc. ...

A workaround is sometimes needed - directories can be easily written as one string,
separated by e. g. '|' - that is a character not allowed in a path - neither in Linux nor Windows.

```
var searchDirsCsv = string.Join("|", _searchDirs);
_searchDirs = searchDirsCsv.Split('|);
```

What do you think?

Comment: StringCollection::AddRange only accepts an array, unfortunately. Thinking it might've been related to that array, I tried StringCollection::Add directly - no dice. The string split/join method works well, though it's not too clear that's what's going on if you edit user.config directly when there's only one entry (normal, in my case).